# No plugin found for prefix '.to.image=fullstack' in the current project (Jib Maven Plugin)

Tags: java, docker, maven, intellij-plugin, jib

I am trying to build a local Docker image with the Jib Maven plugin.
I tried to run this command in my terminal (where I have my IntelliJ project):

`D:\GitHub\fullstack\fullstack> ./mvnw jib:dockerBuild -Djib.to.image=fullstack:v1`

But I get this log message:

```
No plugin found for prefix '.to.image=fullstack' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] a
vailable from the repositories [local (C:\Users\emanuel.butoi\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

I did a little bit of research on Google but I found nothing. I am not familiar with Maven, I am more familiar with Gradle. I will send pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.emanuel</groupId>
    <artifactId>fullstack</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fullstack</name>
    <description>Fullstack project </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>openjdk:8</image>
                    </from>
                    <container>
                        <ports>
                            <port>8080</port>
                        </ports>
                        <format>OCI</format>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-frontend</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- Use the latest released version:
                                  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                        <version>1.11.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>
                            <workingDirectory>../frontend/build</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>v15.4.0</nodeVersion>
                                    <npmVersion>7.3.0</npmVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm run build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-build-folder</id>
                                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>../frontend/build</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
<!--                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static</outputDirectory>-->
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And also the full log with debug flag:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix '.to.image=fullstack' in the current project and in the plugi
n groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\emanuel.butoi\.m2\repository), central (https://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:104) 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments (DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: This is a Maven usage error. It is possible that you have a whitespace character (or some weird special character?) between `-Djib` and `.to.image=...` so that the latter is parsed as a separate token, being recognize as a plugin prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when executing this script in windows powershell. Error disappeared when executed same command in CMD

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer